# Crash in MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using a custom MPMoviePlayerController. It's otherwise working fine, but sometimes I am the application crashes, displaying `"[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:"`.

Kindly provide any solutions regarding the same.

*For the crash I am getting this error code:*

```
CoreFoundation 0x3435864f __exceptionPreprocess 
libobjc.A.dylib 0x314d5c5d objc_exception_throw 
CoreFoundation 0x34358491 [NSException raise:format:arguments:] 
Foundation 0x33532573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] 
MediaPlayer 0x315e8921 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:] 
Foundation 0x334ea183 _nsnote_callback
```

Comment: Please post some code and the error.